# How to filter logical column?

Tags: matlab

I need to get only false value of a logical column, I' ve column data that return this:

```
K>> data(:,4)

ans = 

    [1]
    [1]
    [0]
    [0]
    [0]
    [0]
    [0]
```

I tried this but don't work

```
data= data(strcmp(data(:,4), {false}), :);
```

Output:

```
data = 

    Empty cell array: 0-by-4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your data, it appears you want this:

```
~([data{:,4}])
```

or maybe this

```
find(~([data{:,4}]))
```

Comment: Yep, probably ~logical([data{:,4}])